# UpdateView template only displays pk of a related model, How can a get it to display other fields?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I'm a beginner in django and my problem is rather aesthetic... Right now my template looks like this:
[editSubcategory template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwVZV.png)

the first option in the select tag is the category foreign key previously selected in the CreateView... it would be nice if instead of just showing the foreign key i could also show the name field of the category model to look like the other options in the select tag.

Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Subcategories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        'Categories',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from .models import Subcategories

from .forms import SubcategoriesForm

class EditSubcategory(UpdateView):
    model = Subcategories
    form_class = SubcategoriesForm
    template_name = 'inventory/edit/editSubcategory.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('inventory:subcategoriesList')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EditSubcategory, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Categories.objects.all()
        return context
```

**forms.py**

```
from .models import Categories
from .models import Subcategories

class CategoriesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Categories
        fields = ('name',)

class SubcategoriesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Subcategories
        category = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Categories.objects.all())
        fields = ('name', 'category')
```

**urls.py**

```
path('subcategories/<int:pk>/edit', views.EditSubcategory.as_view(), name='editSubcategory'),
```

**editSubcategory.html**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST" id="editSubcategoryForm">
  {% csrf_token %}

  <div>
    <fieldset class="module aligned">

      <div class="form-row field-name">
        <div>
          <label class="lead">Name: </label>
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" maxlength="50" required id="id_name" value="{{ form.name.value }}"/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <br />

      <div class="form-row field-category">
        <div>
          <label class="lead">Category: </label>
          <select name="category" class="form-control" required id="id_category">
            <option value="{{ form.category.value }}">{{ form.category.value }}</option>
            {% for category in categories.all %}
              <option value="{{category.pk}}">{{category.pk}} -- {{ category.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

      <br />

    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Guardar"/>
</form>
```

Is there any possible way to do this?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind i found the solution myself... i just changed `{{ form.category.value }}` for `{{ object.category }}` in **editSubcategory.html**.

Now it looks like this

```
<select name="category" class="form-control" required id="id_category">
  <option value="{{ form.category.value }}">{{ object.category }}</option>
    {% for category in categories.all %}
      <option value="{{category.pk}}">{{category.pk}} -- {{ category.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```